# How can I store the variables values from views to the Django models?

Tags: python, django

In my terminal the values of name and score are displaying but how to store that two variable values into the particular model(Results).

**models.py:**

```
class Results(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    score = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def html2(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    scores = request.GET.get('scores')
    print(name, scores)
    save_data = Results.objects.create(username=name, score=scores)
    context = {
        'data': save_data
    }

    return render(request,'quiz/html/html2.html',context)
```

**Terminal:**

```
[29/May/2020 13:15:22] "GET /api2/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 1467
Pavana 40
```

I tried this statement but it is displaying the **not null constraint error** so I deleted that statement 
**Error:**

```
    Traceback:

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  296.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: quiz_results.username) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\dev\samplequiz\quiz\views.py" in html2
  58.     save_data = Results.objects.create(username=name, score=scores)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  413.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  717.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  868.         return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1289.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  296.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: quiz_results.username

save_data = Results.objects.create(username=name, score=scores)
```

How can I store the name and scores into the Results model.

Comment: Okay i tried all those things . But it is not displaying .

Comment: post your complete view code with `save_data` code in it and complete error. not just one line

Comment: @Jarvis added once check and if you want anything other than that u can comment here please once fix that error. why it is displaying to store into my Results model?

Comment: @paripalepu where is the definition for this ```quiz_results``` ? ```username``` must be field but you are not doing it.

Comment: you need to have `null=True, blank=True` for username field also. Try that. and set `default=None`

Comment: What is the meaning of the definition for this quiz_results. I did not get that @Jarvis

Comment: Okay i will try

Comment: and make sure you migrate those changes to your db as well.

Comment: Thank you so much it is opening now : -)@Jarvis

Answer (score 1):

It's because all the fields of column in database table are null and that's not good.
You must have atleast one field to be non-empty so remove default='' in username.
i.e. it should look like this `username = models.CharField(max_length=50 )`
After that run makemigrations and migrate commands to sync with database.

Comment: have you ran python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate commands?